# HashTable not adding strings

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm implementing my own HashTable for an assignment, and I need to read from a text file, then add its contents to the HashTable. There are a couple of problems that I have run into,

1) Some hash values for strings are coming out as negative numbers.

2) Some words are not being added.

Here's my code for my hash function:

```
   public int hash(String key) {
        int hashkey = key.hashCode();

        return hashkey % arraySize;
    } // END hash()
```

For the word `computer` it returns the integer `-97`, to get around this I included a if statement to make it positive if the integer is negative. However, even with this the word `computer`, is not added into my HashTable at index `97`.

Some other words that do not get added are: `tree, subtree, record, single` among others. Here are my functions for File I/O and adding them into the HashTable:

```
public static void readParagraph() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    String inputLine;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".\\src\\paragraph.txt"));
        while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] strings = inputLine.split("(\\s|\\p{Punct})+");
            insertParagraph(strings);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
} // END readParagraph()

private static void insertParagraph(String[] strings) {
    Link link;
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (!string.equals("")) {
            link = new Link(string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]", "").toLowerCase());
            paragraph.insert(link);
        }
    }
} // END insertParagraph()
```

Does anyone know what is wrong as to why some words are not being added? Or as to why I am getting negative numbers for hash values?

---

EDIT: More Information

```
public class A4Q3 {
    static HashTable dictionary = new HashTable(1009);
    static HashTable paragraph = new HashTable(164);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readParagraph();
        paragraph.displayTable();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(paragraph.wordCount);
    } // END main()
```

---

```
    public void insert(Link link) {
        String key = link.getKey();
        Link previous = null;
        Link current = first;

        while(current != null && key.compareTo(current.getKey()) > 0) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        if(previous == null) {
            first = link;
        } else {
            previous.setNext(link);
            link.setNext(current);
        }
    } // END insert()
```

---

Link Class:

```
public class Link {
private String data;
private Link next;

public Link(String data) {
    this.data = data;
} // END Link()

public String getKey() {
    return data;
} // END getKey()

public void displayLink() {
    System.out.print(data + " ");
} // END displayLink()

public Link getNext() {
    return next;
} // END getNext()

public void setNext(Link next) {
    this.next = next;
} // END setNext()
```

} // END Link

Comment: Please show us the code where `paragraph` is defined and where `Paragraph.insert(Link)` is defined.

Comment: I edited in the insert method if that's what you're asking about. Let me know if you want more.

Comment: Continuation of this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658382/string-hashtable-implementation

Comment: Negating a negative value in case of Integer.MIN_VALUE will yield itself. Better add `arraySize` if the result is negative.

Comment: I changed the line so that if I get a negative number, I += arraySize, and the words `computer, record` are now showing up, the others are not though.

Comment: Can you post the Link class source as well? Include the constructor part as well please.

Comment: I added the Link class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not handling negative hash codes properly:

```
   public int hash(String key) 
   {
        int hashkey = key.hashCode();

        return hashkey % arraySize;
   }
```

As you said, if `hashkey` is negative, you have issues, so what you can do is change your `hash` function.

**Hash-Code Fix:**

```
   public int hash(String key) 
   {
        int hashkey = key.hashCode();

        return (hashkey & 0x7FFFFFFF) % arraySize;
   }
```

This will perform a `bitwise and` with `hashkey` and `0x7FFFFFFF`, which is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) for 31 1's, ie:

> 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

So, it will turn any input into a positive number, because the `bitwise and` will `and` every digit in `hashkey` with a 1, except for the most-significant digit, which it will `and` with a 0.  Since java uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the most-significant digit is used to indicate the sign.  Since `0 & 1` is 0, this value will now always be positive.

The reason that you're getting negative values for the hashes of the `String` is because of the `hashCode()` for `String`.

**Reason for negative hash values for String:**

```
public int  hashCode() 
{
        int h = hash;

        if (h == 0) 
        {
            int off = offset;
            char val[] = value;
            int len = count;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            {
                h = 31*h + val[off++];
            }

            hash = h;
        }

        return h;
    }
```

Note that your source code may not be the same, but nonetheless, the reason for the negative numbers is. If `h` becomes greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it will wrap around to the `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, ie:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE
```